# JMeter in preprocessor disabling sampler has no effect

Tags: groovy, jmeter, jsr223

I have a Groovy-driven JSR223 preprocessor set on the ThreadGroup in JMeter plan with the idea that when the certain condition like a timeout is met, allow threadGroup to run to completion but disable some samplers based on the naming convention. Something like the following:

```
if (abortTest == true) {
    String name = sampler.getName();
    if (!name.endsWith("crement_count")) { // do not apply to increment or decrement count
        log.warn("Test was aborted. Disabling sampler " + sampler.getName());
        sampler.setEnabled(false);
    }
}
```

Unfortunately regardless of my `sampler.setEnabled(false)` call I can see the matching samplers executing their logic. What am I missing here and how can I achieve the desired effect?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot enable or disable test elements while it's running (I mean efficiently) for [JMeter 5.4.3](https://lists.apache.org/thread/dbg1bxywcwx5vtdwqf8ownf7ppgqjn41) , the easiest would be putting your Samplers under the [If Controller](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/six-tips-for-jmeter-if-controller-usage) and use the [__groovy() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__groovy) as the If Controller's condition.

Comment: Thanks Dmitri. The problem is with preprocessor I can apply logic to multiple samplers instead of attaching controller to each sampler individually. Also I'm curious about your contradiction "cannot" vs "efficiently". In my mind if you cannot then efficiency has nothing to do with it